# Basic commands not working i.e: -bash: ls: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, command-line, ls, path

I'm new to Unix and in the process of installing a program for my dissertation I must have played with the PATH for the basic Unix commands such as `ls`. Every time I type `ls` and the directory name I want to list the files for, it comes up as:

```
-bash: ls: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to fix this? Any help is very very much appreciated!

Comment: The reason ls doesn't work but cd does it documented in my answer

Answer (score 36):

### Reset your path right now (i.e. before any sort of logout) with:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

It doesn't get your full PATH restored but basic utilities will be available again.

Here's an example of the sort of thing that happens:

You had a PATH variable (referred to as $PATH when reading from it)

Something like:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin:/home/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/durrantm/.rvm/bin:/h
ome/durrantm/.autojump/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/durrantm/bin:/home/durrantm/.autojump/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/durrantm/.autojump/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:
/home/durrantm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/durrantm/.rvm/bin:/home/durrantm/.rvm/bin:/home/durrantm
/.rvm/bin
```

You tried to add to it, but you accidentally used

```
PATH=PATH:other_dir
```

instead of

```
PATH=$PATH:other_dir
```

and the result was that your path became

```
PATH:other_dir
```

and then all the utilities like ls and sed don't work

You can fix the minimal set by doing

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

which is particularly useful if a login dot files is messing up your PATH
Check your .bashrc and/or .bash_profile files for any PATH changes.

As Greg says you can also just log out (or safer option, open a new window in case logging in to the machine is now broken - has happened to me, means even non-interactive logins have been broken!) and then echo $PATH from a new window.

The same thing happens when you do `PATH=` with no values.  It 'wipes out' your current path and causes these problems.

As for *why*, when you have these problems cd works and ls doesn't work:

- `cd` is a "built-in" command that doesn't need your PATH to find the program
- `ls` is a program and need to use PATH to find where it is.

You can see this with:

```
$ builtin ls
-bash: builtin: ls: not a shell builtin
14:47:29 mdurrant C02MH2DQFD58 /Users/mdurrant
$ builtin cd
14:47:31 mdurrant C02MH2DQFD58 /Users/mdurrant
$
```

No error means the command is a builtin

### Before 'moving on' (or logging out)...

Make sure to test any changes (**particularly** those to .bashrc, .profile, etc that are doing PATH  setting commands) by opening a new window or doing source ~/.bash_profile to run it. It's also a good practice to keep the window and editor (when you are changing the .bash_profile file) open in case your changes don't work and prevent you from opening new windows to edit the file. Though you can still use TextEdit or another simple editor to change the file (avoiding command line and vi for example).  Be careful NOT to reboot if/when your shell is broken or you may not even be able to login. and that is really really bad (without another account to `su` from you are hosed). Has happened to me!

### My 'extra account' fix was also a life saver then though and highly recommended for all (do it now!)

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot! I just reset the path, but when I open a new terminal window the same thing happens. I then did more ~/.bash_profile to check for any changes and it shows this: export PATH=

Comment: Is that normal?

Comment: Also, when I echo $PATH I get no results..not sure if that is normal or not

Comment: @Mariaa how do you reset the path tell the file or command.

Comment: Yes that `PATH=` with no values will lose all your PATH directories which will lead to command like ls (which are just a program at the end of the day) not working.  Remove that line or comment it out with a # at the beginning, e.g. `# PATH=`

Comment: Make sure to test any changes by opening a new window or doing `source ~/.bash_profile` to run it.  It's also a good practice to keep the window and editor (where you are changing the .bash_profile file) open in case your changed don't work and prevent you from opening new windows to edit the file.  Though you can still use TextEdit or another simple editor to change the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you save my hours

Answer (score 8):

The changes you've made to `PATH` are likely temporary. Close the shell you're in with `exit` and reopen it.

In the event that you have edited a file that sets the `PATH` for newly opened shells, specify the full path to commands to fix whatever you've changed (eg. `/usr/bin/vim`).

Comment: Hello! Thanks (: I tried doing this but it doesn't work. I'm guessing I really did do something weird. I remember using vim to do something with PATH and then everything just got messed up. Ugh, wish I knew more computer language to get this thing sorted!

Comment: is `/usr/bin` or any `bin` directory in your path? @Mariaa

Comment: jgr208: this is my Path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: @Mariaa you didnt delete bin or anything and you have read access to the files correct?

Comment: However, I only can see this or use any command when I input PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin this in a new terminal window..otherwise I cannot use any of the commands. It's not recognising them :S

Comment: @jgr208 I don't think I deleted anything. I have a feeling I move things around, but not sure where Ive moved them

Comment: @Mariaa how about your permissions to the folders? can you cd to any directory?

Comment: @jgr208 Yes I can cd to any directory. But can't use any other commands. It says: no such file or directory. Does it think the commands are files??

Comment: they are files, in linux everything is a file even a device. basically you either deleted, moved, or changed to bad permissions and are out of luck. you will have to reinsall the system.

Comment: see my answer for why cd works and ls doesn't work.

Comment: Just comment out the PATH= and your system will probably be fine.

Comment: How do I reinstall the system? Ive tried to reinstall Mac OS X yosemite (that's what I'm working on) and nothing happened..not sure if this is what you mean? @jgr208

Comment: I will try to comment out the PATH= now. Thanks a lot. Sorry, I'm so new to this, but I like it! Just it gets fixed :S

Comment: @Mariaa why did you leave that major detail out. Well i guess you are SOL. I am not sure if there is any free mac image to use.

Comment: Haha sorry about that. I fixed it! What happened was I changed the whole export PATH= TextEdit file. I opened by .bash_history and went through every detail. I found my original PATH and copied that into the TextEdit and it works. Basically, I deleted PATH..LOL. At least learned some new things about terminal! Thank you all for your help. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for those who logged out after editing the `.bash_profile`, which means you're probably in a situation where you can't use your login screen.

I can't ensure you this will work for you.

### Short Answer

If, for some reason, you don't even have access to a shell,
switch to a virtual console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and login. 
Once you're at a shell prompt,
use `command -p <insert_command_here>` to edit the file in question,
where *`<insert_command_here>`* is something like `nano .bash_profile`.

### Long Answer

I'm using Manjaro, but I doubt that means anything in this scenario.

I was in the login screen. I typed my credentials and then nothing happened. As nothing was working anymore, I had no prompt to work with. I could move my cursor just fine, but none of the login screen buttons worked.

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. I now had a console terminal to work with. I could go back to the previous screen with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but that wasn't necessary.

I was met with a login prompt and filled in my credentials.

I tried using the commands am used to working with, but nothing worked. I'd get the default:

```
-bash: something_something: command not found.
```

But, I found that I COULD use `cd`, but I couldn't list directory contents with `ls`. I did some research and found out that `cd` is a built-in command. I wanted to confirm that I could work with built-in commands and found a way to display all of them:

```
compgen -b
```

I was now met with a lot of commands I could work with. I had no idea what most of them do. I could recognize commands such as `source`, `cd`, `echo` and `exit`. I couldn't find any good material explaining how to use these built-in commands. Maybe I just didn't search well enough. Anyway, since `help` is also a built-in command, I tried using it on some of the built-in commands. Eventually I did:

```
help command
```

one of the options was:

> `command -p`
>
>   Use a default value for
>   **`PATH`**
>   that is guaranteed to find all of the default utilities.

That sounded pretty useful, so I went ahead and tried to do:

```
command -p ls
```

And it worked. Now I figured that I just needed to edit the `.bash_profile` file and so I did:

```
cd ~
command -p nano .bash_profile
```

I then deleted the few lines I had added that had messed up my path. If you don't know which lines that is, then I suppose you'd be safe with some sort of default path. I can imagine that's a thing. If it wasn't `.bash_profile` that caused the issue for you, then I suppose you can try editing the file that did.

I then rebooted the system and everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me when after i installed Andriod Stuido, and wrote the wrong path to SDK. Got multiple export error: not a valid identifier. And all commands did not work. I had to open bash_profile in Notepad (outside the terminal) and remove the wrong PATH.